# How to use Tweepy Bot with Alexa Skill

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, alexa-skills-kit

I have created a tweepy bot that automates tweets to my twitter feed. How would I go about implementing this within an alexa skill. Where if I  tell alexa " automate...." It will do what my tweepy bot does and automate my tweets. I havent been able to find resources online , to help me link the twitter api to alexa.